# Any one of the field should not be null in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a post model  Which allows users to post Caption(text) image video gif audio or all of them

My question is what if they want to post an audio clip without caption or video without a caption or a photo without a video
 how do I make them post at least one thing thing

Because I can't make all fields null or not null

Comment: based on the 0 detail you have provided, I can advise for you to use javascript to validate on the frontend what is being passed through the form, assuming thats how you are dealing with it. Other than that I dont believe anybody will be able to help you, given your question is poorly asked. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I asked this question from the mobile website, so couldn't provide the code and wanted quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious solution: use a distinct model for each kind of post instead of a single one-size-never-fits-all one. This way each model has it's own validation (and rendering and whatever...).

Comment: Thanks you Bruno. Was thinking of that too